NetworkManager is missing support for 'l2tp' VPN connections on SteamOS
I'm trying to connect to my company's VPN from my Steam Deck. I've gone ahead and setup my VPN connection as you can see from here:

My company says it has to be L2TP so that is what I've chosen, but when I right click on it and say "Connect"

I get a popup that says:

NetworkManager is missing support for 'l2tp' VPN connections on SteamOS


When I click on "Install", it takes me to the "Discover" app, but it can't find or install it. It says and shows the following:

Could not open appstream:network-manager-l2tp because it was not found in any available software repositories.



So, how can I actually get this installed and get my L2TP VPN working on SteamOS?

If it helps, this is my system info:


If I'm not mistaken, SteamOS is based on Arch Linux, then the package name is networkmanager-l2tp, not network-manager-l2tp:

https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/networkmanager-l2tp/

